# Laravel Custom Log

Tags: php, laravel, логирование

Заметил одну очень странную особенность, которой, как по мне, быть вообще не должно (либо я делаю что-то не так).

Хочу просто записывать логи в другой файл, и делаю это как всегда вот так:

1. В `logging.php` добавляю свою запись

```
        'customLog' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/custom.log'),
            'level' => 'info',
        ],
```

2. В нужном файле пользуюсь ей

```
\Log::channel('customLog')->info('Hello World!');
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
[2022-07-05 12:42:16] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [customlog] is not defined.
```

Потратил примерно минут 30, но так и не понял в чём ошибка, весь кэш очищен и в других проектах работает.

Сделал вот так и всё заработало:

```
Log::build([
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/infoUser.log'),
        ])->info('Hello World!');
```

Сейчас всё работает, но так и не понял в чём заключается ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

var_dump ( 'customLog' == 'customlog' ); // false
```

Автор показывает что использует имя "customLog", а на деле в коде у него прописано "customlog", т.е. буква "L" виновник.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]